# Problems generalizing Scala type classes

Tags: scala, typeclass

While working on a Scala project that used the Type Class pattern, I ran into what appears to be a serious problem in how the language implements the pattern: Since Scala type-class implementations must be managed by the programmer and not the language, any variable belonging to a type-class can never become annotated as a parent type unless its type-class implementation is taken with it.

To illustrate this point, I've coded up a quick example program. Imagine you were trying to write a program that could handle different kinds of employees for a company and could print reports on their progress. To solve this with the type-class pattern in Scala, you might try something like this:

```
abstract class Employee
class Packer(boxesPacked: Int, cratesPacked: Int) extends Employee
class Shipper(trucksShipped: Int) extends Employee
```

A class hierarchy modelling different kinds of employees, simple enough. Now we implement the ReportMaker type-class.

```
trait ReportMaker[T] {
    def printReport(t: T): Unit
}

implicit object PackerReportMaker extends ReportMaker[Packer] {
    def printReport(p: Packer) { println(p.boxesPacked + p.cratesPacked) }
}

implicit object ShipperReportMaker extends ReportMaker[Shipper] {
    def printReport(s: Shipper) { println(s.trucksShipped) }
}
```

That's all well and good, and we can now write some kind of Roster class that might look like this:

```
class Roster {
    private var employees: List[Employee] = List()

    def reportAndAdd[T <: Employee](e: T)(implicit rm: ReportMaker[T]) {
       rm.printReport(e)
       employees = employees :+ e
    }
}
```

So this works. Now, thanks to our type-class, we can pass either a packer or a shipper object into the reportAndAdd method, and it will print the report and add the employee to the roster. However, writing a method that would attempt to print out the report of every employee in the roster would be impossible, without explicitly storing the rm object that gets passed to reportAndAdd!

Two other languages that support the pattern, Haskell and Clojure, don't share this problem, since they deal with this problem. Haskell's stores the mapping from datatype to implementation globally, so it is always 'with' the variable, and Clojure basically does the same thing. Here's a quick example that works perfectly in Clojure.

```
    (defprotocol Reporter
      (report [this] "Produce a string report of the object."))

    (defrecord Packer [boxes-packed crates-packed]
      Reporter
      (report [this] (str (+ (:boxes-packed this) (:crates-packed this)))))
    (defrecord Shipper [trucks-shipped]
      Reporter
      (report [this] (str (:trucks-shipped this))))

    (defn report-roster [roster]
      (dorun (map #(println (report %)) roster)))

    (def steve (Packer. 10 5))
    (def billy (Shipper. 5))

    (def roster [steve billy])

    (report-roster roster)
```

Apart from the rather nasty solution of turning the employee list into type List[(Employee, ReportMaker[Employee]), does Scala offer any way to solve this issue? And if not, since the Scala libraries make extensive use of Type-Classes, why hasn't it been addressed?

Comment: This is yet another example of subtyping messing up everything. If you think of your employee subclasses as constructors (in the Haskell sense) instead of as subtypes, you'll find that the type class approach is much more comfortable.

Comment: I'm not sure Haskell would solve this problem in the way you think it would. Haskell's standard list type is not heterogeneous, so all elements would have the same typeclass instance. The idea of putting distinct types `Packer` and `Shipper` in the same list just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

The way you'd typically implement an algebraic data type in Scala would be with `case` classes:

```
sealed trait Employee
case class Packer(boxesPacked: Int, cratesPacked: Int) extends Employee
case class Shipper(trucksShipped: Int) extends Employee
```

This gives pattern extractors for the `Packer` and `Shipper` constructors, so you can match on them.

Unfortunately, `Packer` and `Shipper` are also distinct (sub)types, but part of the pattern of encoding an algebraic data type in Scala is to be disciplined about ignoring this. Instead, when distinguishing between a packer or shipper, use pattern matching as you would in Haskell:

```
implicit object EmployeeReportMaker extends ReportMaker[Employee] {
  def printReport(e: Employee) = e match {
    case Packer(boxes, crates) => // ...
    case Shipper(trucks)       => // ...
  }
}
```

If you have no other types for which you need a `ReportMaker` instance, then perhaps the type class isn't needed, and you can just use the `printReport` function.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because, as you said, type classes are only used when you know someone is going to need to add more data types later on. For example, the author of the employee code might think that somewhere later down the line someone will need to add a Manager class. But since you're using pattern matching to solve the problem, he can't add the class unless he modifies the library code itself. Which he may not be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

> *However, writing a method that would attempt to print out the report of every employee in the roster would be impossible, without explicitly storing the rm object that gets passed to reportAndAdd!*

Not sure of your precise problem.  The following should work (obviously with separate reports concatenated at the I/O output point):

```
def printReport(ls: List[Employee]) = {
  def printReport[T <: Employee](e: T)(implicit rm: ReportMaker[T]) = rm.printReport(e)
  ls foreach(printReport(_))
}
```

However, doing I/O somewhere down the method-call-tree (or in methods called iteratively) is against the 'functional philosophy'.  Better to generate individual sub-reports as String / List[String] / other precise structure, bubble them all the up to the outermost method and do I/O in a single hit.  E.g.:

```
trait ReportMaker[T] {
  def generateReport(t: T): String
}
```

(insert implicit Objects similar to Q ...)

```
def printReport(ls: List[Employee]) = {
  def generateReport[T <: Employee](e: T)(implicit rm: ReportMaker[T]): String = rm.generateReport(e)
  // trivial example with string concatenation - but could do any fancy combine :)
  someIOManager.print(ls.map(generateReport(_)).mkString("""\n""")))
}
```